# Как закрыть material-dialog и завершить анимацию до перехода на другой route или отключить анимацию?

Tags: angular

У меня реализована прокрутка страницы вверх при переходе с одного роута на другой, все работает нормально пока я не перехожу на роут по ссылке которая расположена в material dialog.
Оказалось что material dialog устанавливает класс "cdk-global-scrollblock" на тэг html, который в свою очередь навешивает стили position: fixed;  width: 100%; при которых элементарный window.scroll не работает... совсем...

Но самое забавное, что это состояние из-за анимации остается довольно долго после закрытия диалога, настолько долго, что периодически мы успеваем перейти на другой роут и естественно остаемся на том же месте. В итоге window.scroll везде в компоненте работает через раз, а scrollPositionRestoration не работает от слова совсем.

Я попробовал снять класс "cdk-global-scrollblock" через beforeClosed и в нем же прокрутить, и увидел [такую картину](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-tfwtry?file=app/example/example-dialog/example-dialog.component.ts)
Я прокручиваю страницу вниз, открываю диалог, закрываю, страница прокручивается вверх сразу же снова спускается вниз.

Единственный рабочий вариант это делать переход не по ссылке, а по событию afterClosed, но мне кажется это костыльное решение.

Мне просто надо отключить такое поведение mat-dialog. Буду рад советам

Comment: по твоему описанию я предполагаю, что у тебя `routerLink="/page"` внутри компонента. Там очень большая связка, есть `MatDialogContainer` который реализует анимации по спеке материала, отключить их нельзя. `MatDialogContainer` стоит позади всех, вперед него идет `OverlayRef` и `DialogRef`. События завершения анимаций - асинхронные, поэтому `DialogRef` подписывается на событие `animationStateChanged` и фильтрует по `done`, после этого он уничтожает оверлей, и в самом конце генерирует `afterClosed`. Ты можешь выполнять роутинг извне - подписавшись на событие `afterClosed`

Comment: при закрытии диалогового окна ты можешь передавать данные в `close`, например `close('/page')`, т.е. в данных будет просто ссылка, а извне выполнять навигацию `afterClosed.subscribe(url => url && this.router.navigateByUrl(url))`. Так ты будешь уверен, что навигация произойдет только после того, как скрытие контейнера проанимируется и диалоговое окно закроется

Comment: я не вдавался в подробности, что происходит в примере, который ты прикрепил, но  `querySelector(cdk-scrollblock)` точно делать не надо :)

Comment: я пришел к такому решению через afterClosed, но мне кажется оно кастыльным, ведь есть routerLink зачем же он тогда. Кажется решение должно быть простым и лежать на поверхности. Неужели подругому нельзя... querySelector(cdk-scrollblock) я просто эксперементировал))))

Comment: > `Костыль — в программировании, быстрое "уродливое" решение проблемы, иначе требующей долгогосрочного и ресурсоемкого исправления.` - не вижу в данном решении долгогосрочного и ресурсоемкого исправления =))

Comment: > `ведь есть routerLink зачем же он тогда` - эта директива не имеет отношения к диалоговому окну материала и ожидания его скрытия (как и сам роутинг), все что она делает изнутри это вызывает navigateByUrl` за тебя :)